# R remove objects from a list with if else statement

Tags: r, list, if-statement, for-loop

I have a list of data frames, and would like to remove those with less than 2 rows off from mylist:

```
a<-data.frame(x=c(1:4),y=c("m", "n", "o", "p"))
b<-data.frame(x=c(2:6),y=c("q", "w", "e", "r", "t"))
c<-data.frame(x=c(6,7),y=c("j","k"),z=c("$","#"))
d<-data.frame(x="9",y="q",z="+")
mylist<-list(a,b,c,d)

for (i in length(mylist)){
if (nrow(mylist[[i]])<=2){
mylist<-mylist[-i]
}
else{
mylist<-myslit
}}
```

However it only seemed to remove data.frame d. Data frame c is still in "mylist" after running the for loop.

Comment: +1 for showing what you already tried, and providing a working example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this more easily using an apply loop:

```
row_lt2 <- which(sapply(mylist, nrow) < 2)
mylist[-row_lt2]
[[1]]
  x y
1 1 m
2 2 n
3 3 o
4 4 p

[[2]]
  x y
1 2 q
2 3 w
3 4 e
4 5 r
5 6 t

[[3]]
  x y z
1 6 j $
2 7 k #
```

Notice I use negative indexing to remove items instead of selecting them.

Comment: I really love the expressiveness of this functional solution in favor of a more imperative style using a for loop. It is much shorter, in more understandable in my opinion.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I agree about the expressiveness of the functional style. This can be made even for succinct with the `Filter` function. (See my answer below.)

Answer (score 10):

To add to the other answers: this is exactly the type of thing the higher-order `Filter` function is made for:

```
> Filter(function(x) {nrow(x) >= 2}, mylist)
[[1]]
  x y
1 1 m
2 2 n
3 3 o
4 4 p

[[2]]
  x y
1 2 q
2 3 w
3 4 e
4 5 r
5 6 t

[[3]]
  x y z
1 6 j $
2 7 k #
```

Comment: @lamushidi No problem. Take a look at the other functions available on the same help page as `?Filter`. They can be quite useful.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this procedure using `for` because the indices change. Using `for`, after removing line 2, you will examine line 3, but you need examine line 2 again (because the line 2 isn't more the same line as before). Change it to `repeat` or `while`.

```
a<-data.frame(x=c(1:4),y=c("m", "n", "o", "p"))
b<-data.frame(x=c(2:6),y=c("q", "w", "e", "r", "t"))
c<-data.frame(x=c(6,7),y=c("j","k"),z=c("$","#"))
d<-data.frame(x="9",y="q",z="+")
mylist<-list(a,b,c,d)

i <- 1
while (i <= length(mylist)) {
 if (nrow(mylist[[i]])<=2){
  mylist<-mylist[-i]
 }
 else{
  i <- i+1
 }
}
```

Or just use @Paul solution... :P

Comment: I just skipped the OP's suggestion, but your are totally right that a for loop is not really useful here.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra sapply will always be superior, but `for` can be used too, see my answer

Comment: Although you take a bit of a different approach than the OP, creating a new one excluding the matches, in stead of deleting the matches from the list.

Answer (score 3):

Paul has provided an answer already, but your mistake has not been pointed out.

Your code has two problems. First, you need to supply a range to your loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(mylist))
```

or 
    for (i in seq_along(length(mylist)))

Without this, your initialization looked like `for (i in 4)` after evaluation, meaning that only one iteration was run, removing element 4 and not even looking at all previous elements.

However, if you fix that problem, another one emerges. Namely, your list no longer has 4 elements after removing element 3. It only has 3 elements, while your `i` index will go up until 4, resulting in `subscript out of bounds` error.

Therefore one can only suggest the approach using apply, as described by @Paul.

Also, opposed to the assertion otherwise, it is possible to achieve the same using `for` loop, only your approach needs to be slightly different:

```
for (i in 1:length(mylist)) {
    if (nrow(mylist[[i]])>2)
    {
        mylist2[i]<-mylist[i]
    }
}  
print(mylist2)
```

Here you select list elements that are greater than 2, and assign them to a new list. `Sapply` will be more speedy though.

Comment: +1 nice solution using a `for` loop. If `mylist` is big, you could preallocate it first, saving a lot of memory and time.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I don't see how one could specify the size of mylist2 here, except by using your approach, which renders the whole loop obsolete :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference between `(i in length(mylist))` and `(i in 1:length(mylist))`. A common mistake I often made.

Answer (score 0):

For a few special cases, other methods mentioned above didn't work, although `while` could work. I did find that if you use Rcoster's approach `while` without adding an evaluation of the returned list, it would still return the wrong answer -- since every time when the condition `i<=length(mylist)` got evaluated, the length of `mylist` can change, due to the deletion of the `mylist[-i]`. Therefore, the `while` evaluation could stop before it reaches all unwanted elements in the list.

For example, in my case, I wanted to make sure all length of `mylist[[i]]<=4`. The list is very large (2284879 elements to start with). When the first time I ran the `while` evaluation, the program stopped before taking out all `mylist[[i]]>4` because the length of `mylist` got smaller. I had to use `table(lengths(mylist))` to judge whether all unwanted lists were taken out. If not, then run the `while` loop again. Luckily it only took two runs. But I thought it is necessary to point it out, in case someone else came here and try to use this `while` approach.

PS. `for` loop should be usable too, if some evaluation added to judge whether re-run is needed.